# Why is the control not reaching the loop?

Tags: java

I wrote a `Box` class which has two constructors. One is `Box()` which is a default constructor and meant to be executed when the user enters blank spaces, the other one is `Box(length, breadth, height)` which is executed when the user in fact enters input for a given Box. So I wrote the class `Box` in the following way:

```
class Box{

    private int length, breadth, height;

    //Default Constructor
    Box(){
        System.out.print("No Parameter given"); 
    }

    //Parameterized Constructor
    Box(int l, int b, int h){
        length=l; breadth=b; height=h;
    }

    int volume(){
        return breadth*height*length;
    }
}
```

So, here is the `main()` function where I am trying to implement the code. My intention is to call the default constructor when the input is blank spaces and calculate the voulme by the sceond constructor if the input is not empty.

```
class mybox{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
            System.out .print("Enter length, breadth and height->>");
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            int length1=scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Length= "+length1);
            int breadth1=scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Breadth= "+breadth1);
            int height1=scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Height= "+height1);

            if( length1== Integer.parseInt(" ") 
                && breadth1== Integer.parseInt(" ") 
                && height1== Integer.parseInt(" ") ){
                Box samplebox=new Box();
            }
            else {
                Box samplebox=new Box(length1, breadth1, height1);
                try{
                    System.out.println("The volume of the box is " + samplebox.volume());
                } catch (ArithmeticException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
     }
}
```

In Eclipse, I am getting a warning "The value of the local variable samplebox is not used" in the line `Box samplebox=new Box()`. So where is the error in the code?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(" ") should throw exception, when control reaches that line

Comment: @upog, Nah, no exception is being thrown, but is the usage of parseInt being wrong here?? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
scanner.nextInt()
```

cannot accept an empty string input. It will wait for a valid number/char input.

`Integer.parseInt(" ")` will throw an exception as empty space is not a valid integer string.

Comment: Quite right. In that case, how can I make it take an empty string?

Comment: @Mistu4u You will have to use Scanner.nextLine but that returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
if(length1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && breadth1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && height1== Integer.parseInt(" "))
{
    Box samplebox=new Box();
}
else
{
    Box samplebox=new Box(length1, breadth1, height1);
    try{
        System.out.println("The volume of the box is "+ samplebox.volume());
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you are declaring two separate variables named `samplebox`, one in each branch of the `if`. The first one is not being used before it goes out of scope. Assigning a value to a variable is not "using" the value; Eclipse notices that the assigned value cannot be used anywhere and is warning you that there may be a problem with your code.

One solution is to simply do something with `samplebox` inside the `if` branch after you assign a value. Alternatively, you can do this:

```
Box samplebox;
if(length1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && breadth1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && height1== Integer.parseInt(" "))
{
    samplebox=new Box();
}
else
{
    samplebox=new Box(length1, breadth1, height1);
    try{
        System.out.println("The volume of the box is "+ samplebox.volume());
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// . . . use samplebox
```

By moving the declaration itself out of the `if` branch, you will be assigning to a variable that has a scope greater than the `if` statement itself.

Comment: Your method is absolutely correct. But an empty string is not being taken as input and as @juned wrote in his answer, it is waiting for a valid character. So in that case, how can I make it take an empty string?

Comment: @Mistu4u - I was answering your question about the message from Eclipse. I suggest that you simply use the test `if (length1==0 && breadth1==0 && height1==0)...` There's no need to parse constant strings; simply put in the integers. Note that `scanner.nextInt()` returns an `int` value, so `length1`, `breadth1`, and `height1` cannot be "blank" in any way. For that you would need to read a string as juned suggests.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(length1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && breadth1== Integer.parseInt(" ") && height1== Integer.parseInt(" "))
{
    // Here you assign a variable samplebox that is local (within the {})
    // but you don't use it for anything.
    // i.e. The value of the local variable samplebox is not used
    //
    Box samplebox=new Box();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also allow any string from the user then, you have to use `scanner.nextLine()` and then convert this string to Integer. Something like this:

```
    System.out.print("Enter length, breadth and height->>");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String len_str = scanner.nextLine();
    int length1 = 0;
    try {
        length1 = Integer.parseInt(len_str);
    } catch (Exception ef) {
        length1 = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Length= " + length1);
    String br_str = scanner.nextLine();
    int breadth1 = 0;
    try {
        breadth1 = scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception ef) {
        breadth1 = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Breadth= " + breadth1);
    int height1 = 0;
    String he_str = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
        height1 = Integer.parseInt(he_str);
    } catch (Exception ef) {
        height1 = 0;
    }
    height1 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Height= " + height1);
    if (length1 == 0 && breadth1 == 0 && height1 == 0) {
        Box samplebox = new Box();
    } else {
        Box samplebox = new Box(length1, breadth1, height1);
        try {
            System.out.println("The volume of the box is " + samplebox.volume());
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```